# How to add text field or html in ng-multi-select dropdown in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select

Currently i have a multi select drop down with check box default.
Now i want to add a text field near to the value.

Initially i just added pure html in quote, but it doesn't work as i expected.
then i tried to escape the double quotes but it still remain same

```js
dummyArray: Array<any> = [{
    'pan_name': '',
    'pan_label':'',
    'pan_type':'Mul-select',
    'pan_field':'',
    'pan_value':[{'id':1,'name':'xxxx'+'<h2 class=/"fg-white/">AboutUs</h2>`'}]
}]
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <label>{{field.pan_label}}</label>
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select'"
                             [data]="field.pan_value"
                             name="{{field.pan_field}}"
                             [(ngModel)]="field.pan_name"
                             [settings]="dropdownSettings">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

i want to add a text field near to the value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind HTML directly to the view by default for some security reason (XSS).
Angular provide you a service that allow you to sanitize your HTML content and bind it to the view https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer.

For example you can create a pipe that you could use to sanitize your HTML :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```